# Update application with Inno Setup installer

Tags: inno-setup

I am learning how to use Inno Setup to create an installer for my project. I am having an issue though when it comes to updating. I've created the installer, and installed my application successfully. I've then updated my version number within the script and recompiled however when I run the installer it seems to treat it as a new install still.

For example, it will ask me where I want the application to be installed and when I click next then tells me the directory already exists. As the application has already been installed. I expected this bit to be skipped.

Below is my InnoSetup Script

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "SQLite Manager"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0.0.2"
#define MyAppPublisher "Boardies IT Solutions"
#define MyAppURL "http://www.boardiesitsolutions.com"
#define MyAppExeName "SqliteManager.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{98A016AD-2DE2-4FF9-B639-0FDCA0BE41FD}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\Boardies IT Solutions\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName=Boardies IT Solutions
LicenseFile=C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\Terms.txt
OutputBaseFilename=sqliteman
SetupIconFile=C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\Logo.ico
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
UsePreviousAppDir=yes
CreateUninstallRegKey=no
UpdateUninstallLogAppName=no
DisableDirPage=auto

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "quicklaunchicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateQuickLaunchIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked; OnlyBelowVersion: 0,6.1

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\SqliteManager.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\BoardiesITSolutions.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\BoardiesITSolutions.INIReader.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\changelog.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\Middleware.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\MySql.Data.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\System.Data.SQLite.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SqliteManager\SqliteManager\bin\Debug\WhatsNew.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon
Name: "{userappdata}\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: quicklaunchicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: I think (don't have time to verify), that the previous directory is being read from the registry key, which you are not creating when you disabled the `CreateUninstallRegKey` directive.

Comment: Thanks, I've removed this directive however it still runs as if its a new install instead of an update

Comment: The rest should be fine, I think. You've explicitly enabled the `UsePreviousAppDir`, and kept the `DirExistsWarning` directive implicitly set to `auto`, which should not warn the user when they install in the same directory as the previous version. I think the only problem was the missing previous directory information (in registry). Have you uninstalled everything before the test ?

Comment: Hmm, guess the recompile didn't quite go through properly, checked through everything and recompiled it again and now its working. Thanks for your help, do you want to add the your inital comment as an answer and I can accept it

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to write one.

Comment: If I write it you won't get the SO points

Answer (score -5):

I've noticed that little detail
AppId={{98A016AD-2DE2-4FF9-B639-0FDCA0BE41FD}

Looks like you have a missing right curly brace.

Comment: Ok so the left curly brace must be kind of escaped but not the right one?